# iPhone app crash before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, break exception does not assist

Tags: ios, crash

My iPhone app crashes in main.m before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Crash at:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

I tried to add break exception, but I can't find the line its broken. The crash log does not help me.

If I continue with the button of debug it is continue running.

[Debug navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtfyP.png)

[Frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFtQG.png)

Comment: can you share your console report.

Comment: no even console report :(

Comment: Are you using custom fonts? Are you trying to alter the appearance of the status bar ? Your crash log suggests at least one of those things.

Comment: Are you using a custom font? Which framework are you using? Where is the TFont comming from?

Comment: added my framworks to the question,
checking the status bar :)

Comment: @WarrenBurton  I think this is the changes I made in status bar:
    
`-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem was that my break exception was of all exception instead of only objective c exception.

now it is run perfect!